# componentWillReceiveProps not triggered when switch viewcontrollers

Tags: react-native, react-router, react-redux

I am trying to pass a value to next page on react-native based app. It was working on other pages of my app. But it does not work on one of view controllers. This is the code.

### **## This is where I call it ##**

```
class AddProductController extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            avatarSource: [],
            totalImages: [],
            alreadySelect: false,
            currentUser: global.currentUser,
            position: 1,
            isLoading: false,
        };
    }

    next(){
        var advs = new Advs()
        advs.setImages(this.state.totalImages)
        console.log('days3',advs)

        Actions.addDescriptionController({advertisement:advs})
    }
}

export default AddProductController;
```

### This is where it is supposed to print pass

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Image, Dimarketnsions, ScrollView, TouchableWithoutFeedback, TouchableOpacity, TextInput, FlatList, } from 'react-native';
import { Actions, ActionConst } from 'react-native-router-flux';
import {
  View, Container, Header, Title, Content, Text, Button, Icon, Left, Body, Right, Footer, InputGroup, Input, List, ListItem,
} from 'native-base';
import { Col, Row, Grid } from 'react-native-easy-grid';
import FooterSection, { IndexEnum } from '../../components/Footer';
import styles from './styles';
import SearchHeaderWrapper from '../../components/SearchHeaderWrapper';
import { KeyboardAwareScrollView } from 'react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view';

class AddDescriptionController extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            text: '',
            advertisement : ''
        };


    }
    componentWillMount() {

    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        console.log("pass")

    }
```

Comment: componentWillReceiveProps until existing props are changed. So to trigger cmwrp to work change the passing props dynamically. it is very unclear with your attached files how the flow is going.

Comment: yes...It is not clear.. I will post a good one next time. Could you tell me how to change the passing props dynamically

Comment: if you are using redux  then mapstateToProps is responsible for passing props. to the component ... so if you make any change in redux store mapsStateToProps will trigger and pass the newProps to the component then componentWillRecieveProps wil lbe Called 
or If you are passing props from Parent to child then changing those props. via state or any other variable will trigger cmwrp in child.